# widget.unbind removes all callbacks for a sequence not just the funcid callback

Tags: tkinter

I expected `unbind( seq, funcid = _id )` to remove only the `_id` callback from the events bound to that widget and sequence.  Instead it removes all of them.  I get the same behaviour macOS and Linux.

Have I done something wrong or misunderstood the documentation?

```
import tkinter as tk

click1_id = None # The id for the added function. 

def add_binding():
    global click1_id
    print( 'Add Binding', label.bind(), click1_id, end = '  ' ) # Tracing
    if click1_id is None:
        click1_id = label.bind( "<Button>", on_click1(), add = '+' )
        # on_click1() returns a function with sequential numbering.
    print( 'Added Binding', label.bind(), click1_id, '\n' ) # Tracing

def remove_binding():
    global click1_id
    print( 'Remove', click1_id, end = "  " ) # Tracing
    if click1_id:
        print( 'Unbinding', click1_id ) # Tracing

        label.unbind( "<Button>", funcid = click1_id ) 
        # This removes all bindings, not just the funcid 

        click1_id = None
    print( 'Bindings:', label.bind(), 'ID:', click1_id, '\n' ) # Tracing

def on_click0( event ):
    print( "Click: 0", event, 'Widget:', event.widget )

def on_click_root( event ):
    # Detects clicks even if all events on the Label are unbound
    print( "Click root", event, 'Widget:', event.widget, '\n' )

seq = 0
def on_click1():
    """ Returns a function that reports with a sequence number. """ 
    global seq
    seq += 1
    count = seq

    def func( event ):
        print( 'Click:', count, event, 'Widget:', event.widget )
    return func

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label( root, text = 'Click to action' )

doadd = tk.Button( root, text = ' Add  binding ', command = add_binding )
doremove = tk.Button( root, text = 'Remove binding', command = remove_binding )

label.bind( "<Button>", on_click0 )
root.bind( "<Button>", on_click_root )

label.grid( row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 5 )
doadd.grid( row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5 )
doremove.grid( row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5 )

root.mainloop()
```

The tracing report following a series of actions.

```
# Click Label - As expected
Click: 0 <ButtonPress event num=1 x=40 y=15> Widget: .!label        
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=40 y=15> Widget: .!label 

# Click Add Binding - As expected
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=56 y=12> Widget: .!button    

Add Binding ('<Button>',) None  Added Binding ('<Button>',) 140691558063232func 

# Click Label - As expected
Click: 0 <ButtonPress event num=1 x=39 y=14> Widget: .!label
Click: 1 <ButtonPress event num=1 x=39 y=14> Widget: .!label
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=39 y=14> Widget: .!label 

# Click Remove Binding ???
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=58 y=12> Widget: .!button2 

Remove 140691558063232func  Unbinding 140691558063232func
Bindings: () ID: None   # Expected Bindings: ('<Button>',) 

# Click Label - Click: 0 expected - only Click root reported
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=62 y=11> Widget: .!label 

# Click Add Binding
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=74 y=17> Widget: .!button 

Add Binding () None  Added Binding ('<Button>',) 140691567712256func 

# Click Label - Only Click 2 reported
Click: 2 <ButtonPress event num=1 x=48 y=15> Widget: .!label
Click root <ButtonPress event num=1 x=48 y=15> Widget: .!label
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unbind method doesn't work in the way I understood the documentation.  `widget.unbind( sequence, funcid = _id)` unbinds all the callbacks with the sequence, not just the one with `funcid = _id`.  Adding the funcid parameter means the tcl/tk reference to the function is deleted as well as being unbound.

There is [an issue raised for tkinter in 2017](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75666) which is basically the same question with some discussion that clarified things for me.